# How to Get the Current Value of For loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I want to print the current element and the old element of my for loop:

Output:

```
1 

1 3 

1 3 5 

1 3 5 7

1 3 5 7 9
```

```
for current_element in range(1,10,2):
    print(current_element, end= ' ')
```

I get only the last line `" 1 3 5 7 9 "`

Comment: Why do *you* think the loop is executing the way it is, rather than how you’d like it to?  Can you explain its logic (by updating the question)?

Comment: For loops don't have a "current element" or an "old element" - that's just not the terminology we use. The reason you only get one line of output is because your `print` statement puts everything on one line. The reason that each call to `print` prints a single number is because that's what you get out of the `range` that you're using. The question you're asking demonstrates a complete misunderstanding, not of Python, but of *what the code needs to do*. To fix this, you need to talk to your instructor or TA, or an actual discussion forum like Reddit or Quora - Stack Overflow is *not* that.

Comment: You are, presumably, intended to use two nested loops to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not getting the last row but the right diagonal, as you print each value on the same line

You need to save the previous values to achieve your triangle output

```
values = []
for current_element in range(1, 10, 2):
    values.append(current_element)
    print(*values)
```

```
1
1 3      
1 3 5    
1 3 5 7  
1 3 5 7 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the values and print, the below code will give desired result

```
pstr = ""           
for current_element in range(1,10,2):
    pstr = pstr + str(current_element) + " "
    print(pstr)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
for i in range(1, 10, 2):
    for j in range(i):
        print(j, end=' ')
    print()
```